# Allowing user to reorder lined up images on HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I would like to allow a user to reorder lined up images on an HTML page like this one: http://www.blakearchive.org/exist/blake/archive/comparison.xq?selection=compare&copies=all&bentleynum=B1&copyid=urizen.f&java=bb136.B1

Basically, I want to make it so that you can click and drag one image next to another. Can anyone suggest any ways to do this or any image gallery scripts that already do this?

Thanks.

Update:

I tried using jquery sortable, but I'm not sure how to put the jquery in an xquery function. I'm getting a parse error when I do it like this (see ):

```
declare function blake:comparison( )
as node( )*
{
let $initial := request:request-parameter("copyid", ())
let $copyreq := request:request-parameter( "copies", ( ) )
let $bentley := request:request-parameter("bentleynum", ()),
    $bad := collection($g:collection)/bad[@id = $g:copyid],
    $workid :=$bad/substring-before(@id, '.')

let $object := collection($g:collection)/bad[@id = string($g:copyid)]//desc[objtitle/objid/objcode[@code= $bentley]],

        $objectdbi := string($object/@dbi),
    $compwith := string($object/@compwith)

return

<document>
<head><title>William Blake Archive Comparison of {g:work($workid)} </title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="25" style="width:auto;" id="comparison">
<tr>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  });
  </script>

  <ul id="sortable">


{(: print out information from current context:)
g:comparison($g:copyid, $bentley, $objectdbi, "1")}
{
if ($copyreq = 'all')
then 
    for $copies at $pos in if($compwith != "") 
                               then (collection($g:collection)/bad[starts-with(@id, $workid)], collection($g:collection)/bad[starts-with(@id, substring-before( $compwith, "." ) )])
                               else collection($g:collection)/bad[starts-with(@id, $workid)]
    order by $copies//printdate[1]/@value, g:copydesignation(string($copies/@id))
    return
    <p>
        {if(substring-before($copies/@id, ".") = substring-before($compwith, "."))
         then g:comparison(string($copies/@id), substring-after($compwith, "."), $objectdbi, string($pos))
              else if($copies/@id != $g:copyid)
              then g:comparison(string($copies/@id), $bentley, $objectdbi, string($pos))
        else ""}
        </p>

else 
    for $copies at $pos in request:request-parameter("copies", ())
    return
        if(substring-before($copies, ".") = substring-before($compwith, "."))
        then g:comparison(string($copies), substring-after($compwith, "."), $objectdbi, string($pos))
        else g:comparison(string($copies), $bentley, $objectdbi, string($pos))
}

{
    if ($workid = "songsie")
    then 
        for $copies at $pos in collection($g:collection)/bad[starts-with(@id, "s-inn")]
        order by $copies//printdate[1]/@value, g:copydesignation(string($copies/@id))
        return
        <p>
            {if($copies/@id != $g:copyid)
            then g:comparison(string($copies/@id), $bentley, $objectdbi, string($pos)) 
            else ""}
            </p>
    else ""

}   
{
    if ($workid = "s-inn")
    then 
        for $copies at $pos in collection($g:collection)/bad[starts-with(@id, "songsie")]
        order by $copies//printdate[1]/@value, g:copydesignation(string($copies/@id))
        return
            if($copies != $g:copyid)
            then g:comparison(string($copies/@id), $bentley, $objectdbi, string($pos))
            else ""
    else ""
}

</ul>
</tr>
</table>
</body></document>
};

transform:transform( blake:comparison( ), doc("/db/blake/xsl/main.xsl"), ( ) )
```

g:comparison is here from another file:

```
declare function g:comparison($copy as xs:string, $bentley as xs:string, $original as xs:string, $position as xs:string)
as element()*
{
let $object := collection($g:collection)/bad[@id = $copy]//desc[objtitle/objid/objcode[@code= $bentley]],
    $printdate := collection($g:collection)/bad[@id = $copy]//printdate[1]/text(),
    $objid := string($object/objtitle/objid),
    $objectdbi := string($object/@dbi),
    $objectid := string($object/@id),
    $crdate := collection($g:collection)/bad[@id = $copy]//userestrict/date,
    $winwidth := xs:integer($object//windowsize/@width)
    order by $printdate
return
<td valign="top" align="center" style="font-size:smaller;"> 

{if ($objid) then
<div style="min-width:350px;"><p>
{g:copytitle($copy)}<br/>
<a href="{$g:blakeroot}archive/object.xq?objectid={$objectid}&amp;java=no" target="wbamain">{$objid}</a>
</p>
<img src="/blake/images/{lower-case($objectdbi)}.100.jpg"></img>
<!--script>document.write('img 0 is ' + document.images[0].src + ' scale to 300 as ' + ( 300 / document.images[0].width ) );</script-->
<p><a href="javascript:START('{$g:blakeroot}archive/userestrict.xq?copyid={$copy}')"><span style="font-size:smaller">&#169;{$crdate}</span></a>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
</p> </div>
else ()}
</td>
};
```

Comment: Hey, maybe this can help you out: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Comment: Are you using jquery? If so look at jqueryui - http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to put that jquery in an xquery function. See above in the original question for the code.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Recommended_Drag_Types#Dragging_Images

Answer (score 0):

You could try the methods used at: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/

It contains an example and the used code.

Comment: That's not quite what I need. I think the jquery sortable thing is what I need, but I can't seem to get it right in the code above.